# Sum $\frac{1}{2} + 1 + \frac{9}{8}+1+\frac{25}{32}+\frac{36}{64}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\frac{1}{2} + 1 + \frac{9}{8}+1+\frac{25}{32}+\frac{36}{64}+\cdots$ be a series.
I need to calculate its sum using $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n.$$

I was trying to set $x=\frac{1}{2}$, so:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^{n-1}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty (nx^n)'=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^n)''.$$

Then I was differentiating separately:
$$x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^n)'' = x^2\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)''=x^2\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)'=x^2\frac{2(1-x)}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}.$$

And finally calculate the sum:

$$\frac{2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}^3} = 4.$$

But I got the wrong answer.

What did I miss? How do I solve it correctly?

Comment: $x^2 (x^n)^{''} = (n)(n-1)(x^n)$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (nx^n)\ne x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^n)$

Comment: You need to include $n=0$ to summation of the derivatives.  It should no affect the result.

Comment: Going from first derivative to second is incorrect.  You can't simply pull $x$ out.

Comment: I always find it easier to do these staring with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \frac x{1-x}$, differentiate both sides, multiply through by $x$, differentiate again, multiply by $x$ again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain the sum of the following series? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348438/how-to-obtain-the-sum-of-the-following-series-sum-n-1-infty-fracn22n) Found using Approach0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $\frac{1}{2} + 1 + \frac{9}{8}+1+\frac{25}{32}+\frac{36}{64}+\cdots$ be a series.
> Calculate its sum using following relation.
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n$$

Consider following sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{x}{1-x} \tag1$$ where $x \lt 1$ and $x \ne 0$. Differentiate both sides of the equation $(1)$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \frac{(1-x)-x(-1)}{(1-x)^2}=  \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}  \ \Rightarrow \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \tag2$$
Again, differentiate both sides of the equation $(2)$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1} = \frac{(1-x)^2 - 2x(1-x)(-1)}{(1-x)^4} = \frac{(1-x)(1+ x)}{(1-x)^4} = \frac{(1+ x)}{(1-x)^3} $$

$$\therefore \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^n = \frac{x(1+ x)}{(1-x)^3} $$

In your case, apply $x = \frac12$ and you get the solution as $6$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2\left(\frac12\right)^n = \frac{\frac12(1+ \frac12)}{(1-\frac12)^3} = 6$$

Comment: You can't split summation over product

Comment: @ Lalit Tolani: I corrected it. Thought $n$ is a constant for some reason! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the samml trick

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[n(n-1)+n]x^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=x^2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n \right)''+x\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n \right)'$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^k = x\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k\right)'=x\left(x\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k\right)'\right)' = x\left(x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'\right)'=\frac{x (x+1)}{(1-x)^3}
$$